# RadGridView Export to Excel Custom Checkboxes as YES/NO

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I am exporting a Telerik winforms grid to excel, which works fine.  One of the fields I'm exporting is a Checkbox called 'USPerson'.  The text of the USPerson field on export shows as true/false.  I want to change this to YES/NO in the exported file.

Note: I'm able to do this when the grid is displayed by setting up an event to CellFormatting for the grid and doing this:

```
e.CellElement.Text = ((bool) e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["USPerson"].Value) ? "YES" : "NO";
```

How would I do this when exporting to an excel file?

Comment: How are you exporting the data?
If you're not doing so already, export the datatable instead of the grid. You can easily change the datatable values (the grid only displays them) and then export.

Comment: Hi Robert - I am exporting using the built in Export method on the RadGridView control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to introduce changes to cells - both appearance and in value is the CellFormatting event. Here is how to achieve what you need with it:

```
void exporter_CellFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.Export.CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.GridColumnIndex == 2 && e.GridRowIndex >-1)
        {
            string newValue = (bool)e.GridCellInfo.Value ? "YES" : "NO";
            Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model.CellSelection excelCell = (Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model.CellSelection)e.CellSelection;
            excelCell.SetValue(newValue);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and figure I'll write it up here for others to see.

I subscribed to the SpreadExportRenderer.WorkbookCreated event and customized the exported data accordingly to the requirement of turning true/false to YES/NO. I found additional information in the following articles at Telerik:

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/exporting-data/spread-export

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radspreadprocessing/working-with-workbooks/create-open-and-save-workbooks

I was able to scan the column I was interested in and do the conversion.

Thanks.